# iOS How do I find Strings in Apple's private APIs

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

Let's skip the discussion about using the private APIs, it's just for testing something.

I am looking for a way to access hidden field of `MPMediaItem` by using the `value(forProperty:)` but the String I'm looking for is not available publicly. I have looked over `MPMediaItem` header [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MPMediaItem.h) and I could not find what I was looking for however this didn't surprise me because when looking at [MPMediaPlaylist.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MPMediaPlaylist.h) I also couldn't find any info about "`parentPersistentID`" or "`isFolder`" properties both which can be easily accessed by `value(forProperty: "isFolder") as Bool`

Normally you would access Playlist's name or other fields by something like `value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)`, because `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName` is publicly available, `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyIsFolder` is not so we have to use "`isFolder`"

Is it possible to find those hidden Strings? I am wondering if it's a matter of luck when guessing the name or there is a header which contains those Strings

Below are those String which are available publicly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you really need to rethink your application in this point.
I think that one should never play with private APIs, it is made private for a purpose.

But this Objective-C code, could display the private variables:

```
unsigned int o;
Ivar *d = class_copyIvarList([MPMediaItem class], &o);
for(int i=0;i<o;i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getName(d[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
free(d);
```

You also may need the properties, sometimes there are `computed` properties (sorry for the swifty term), these properties also may be private and you may want to know it.

You can also try to add this:

```
objc_property_t *prop = class_copyPropertyList([something class], &l);
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString: property_getName(prop[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't display anything, the loop doesn't start

Comment: Loop doesn't start? It may mean that no Ivars

Comment: Please, check the new edit for the answer.  Also you may use the same mechanism for methods, but of course with a different function.

Comment: Okay, it works but prints only public fields, I checked with MPMediaPlaylist and the field "isFolder" is not shown but it's possible to access it via valueForProperty method
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The problem is that it is not Objective-C properties, `MPMediaItem` seems to have a private internal dictionary where you can only read from it using `valueForProperty:` (`valueForProperty:` is NOT something related to Objective-C, in objective-c you use `valueForKey:`).